# How to get the differences details of two different dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

How to perform below operations on two different dictionaries ?
`dict2` can be very huge. I believe `set` operations is bit slower.

1. get the values of keys of `dict1` from `dict2`, whether same values or different:

```py
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dict2 = {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'd': 5}

# Output: {'a': 3, 'b': 4}

dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dict2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 5}

# Output: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

2. key that's present in `dict1` but not in `dict2`, output as shown below

```py
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 6}
dict2 = {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'd': 5}

# Output: {'c': 6}
```

3. all the keys of dict1 exist in `dict2`, get values of keys of `dict1` from dict2

```py
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 6}
dict2 = {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 6, 'd': 5}

# Output: {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 6}
```

Tried below methods:

```
def keys_in_dict1_but_not_in_dict2(dict1, dict2):
   d1 = {}
   for key in dict1.keys():
      if not key in dict2:
         d1[key] = dict1[key]

   return d1

def keys_in_dict1_and_dict2(dict1, dict2):
      d1 = {}
      for key in dict1.keys():
         if key in dict2:
            d1[key] = dict2[key]

      return d1
```

I could have used `sets`, but that's slower when dictionary length increases. And this above conventional looping may increase the time (along with complexity), as dictionary length increases.
What would be efficient and best way to handle ?
Is this the right approach or any other better approach to handle these scenarios ?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. You provided the requirements and an attempt, but no indication of what the attempt does or why you're unhappy with it. Please see [ask]

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for that. I could have used sets, but that's slower when dictionary length increases. And this conventional loop may increase the time.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have updated details.

Comment: So the code works? Also, what do you mean by "I could have used sets"? Why do you think it would be slower?

Comment: Are you aware that `dict.keys()` is set-like and you can just difference them directly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as follows: iterate through the keys of one dictionary, decide if they are in another, and extract the appropriate values. You can either do both steps in one loop, or separate the key checking from the value extraction. The choice will depend on the number of keys and the number of values you want to copy.

To do the operations together, you would use the loops you show, possibly optimized as comprehensions. To separate out the operations, you would use the fact that `dict.keys()` returns a set-like view backed by the dictionary itself. This allows you to do selection much faster than converting to a `set`.

1. Keys of `dict1` that appear in `dict2` are `dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()`. Your two options are therefore

   ```
   {key: dict2[key] for key in dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()}
   ```

   AND

   ```
   {key: dict2[key] for key in dict1 if key in dict2}
   ```
2. Keys of `dict1` that don't appear in `dict2` are `dict1.keys() - dict2.keys()`. Your two options are therefore

   ```
   {key: dict1[key] for key in dict1.keys() - dict2.keys()}
   ```

   AND

   ```
   {key: dict1[key] for key in dict1 if key not in dict2}
   ```
3. In this case, no optimization is possible: all the keys need to be iterated over:

   ```
   {key: dict2[key] for key in dict1}
   ```

To find out which option works fastest for 1. and 2., you will have to run a benchmark specific to your data size and ratio of overlap. For example, if `len(dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()) < len(dict1)`, you will save a lot of overhead in `__getitem__` by using the first approach for 1. But if most keys are present, then the overhead of doing a set operation on `keys()` may overtake the computation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dictionary comprehension.

1. get the values of keys of dict1 from dict2:

   `part1 = {key: dict2[key] for key in dict1 if key in dict2}`
2. key that's present in dict1 but not in dict2:

   `part2 = {key: value for key, value in dict1.items() if key not in dict2}`
3. get values of keys of dict1 from dict2"

   `part3 = {key: dict2[key] for key in dict1}`

Comment: Thank you. How's it different ? I see that you have just used dictionary comprehension, in additional to my solution. Still is this better approach ?